# Spring Security: How to get details from the principal?

Tags: java, spring-security

Using spring boot and spring security, the details of user are available in principal object. But it has only few methods to retrieve details, like `getName()`.

How do I get other details out of it?

Currently my class looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoOAuth2Application {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoOAuth2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

It returns this,

```
{
  "authorities": [
    {
      "authority": "ROLE_USER"
    }
  ],
  "details": {
    "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
    "sessionId": "43Fxxxxxx",
    "tokenValue": "ya29.xxxxxxxxx",
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "decodedDetails": null
  },
  "authenticated": true,
  "userAuthentication": {
    "authorities": [
      {
        "authority": "ROLE_USER"
      }
    ],
    "details": {
      "id": "106xxxxx",
      "email": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
      "verified_email": true,
      "name": "xxxx yyyyyy",
      "given_name": "xxxxxx",
      "family_name": "yyyyy",
      "link": "https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx",
      "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/xxxxxx/photo.jpg",
      "locale": "en"
    },
    "authenticated": true,
    "principal": "106xxxxx",
    "credentials": "N/A",
    "name": "106xxxxxxx"
  },
  "principal": "106xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "clientOnly": false,
  "credentials": "",
  "oauth2Request": {
    "clientId": "xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scope": [],
    "requestParameters": {},
    "resourceIds": [],
    "authorities": [],
    "approved": true,
    "refresh": false,
    "redirectUri": null,
    "responseTypes": [],
    "extensions": {},
    "refreshTokenRequest": null,
    "grantType": null
  },
  "name": "106xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

But instead of returning all the data, I'd like to return only specific data I need. How do I get that data(specifically email, name, link, picture).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoOAuth2Application {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Authentication user(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> properties = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
        return properties.get("email");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoOAuth2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object representing the subset of data you want to be returned from the endpoint. Then copy the data from the principal to the new object and finally return the new object.

Comment: But how do I copy the data? The principal object does not provide any methods to read it's contents.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting it yet. Do you suggest that I create another class, write a cast to it from Principle, and use it? In that case, how would I access any of those details from Principle, if it is not exposing them? Also, Principle has over 50 implementations, and I don't know how to figure out which one is being used.

Comment: I was suggesting you cast the Principal object into the implementation that will presumably have accessor methods. As for getting the implementation class, you can either start the server in debug mode or put in a log statement for principal.class.getName()

Comment: Thanks. I tried casting it into the classes that were found while debugging. Neither of them have any methods to access the data. I think the data is not even stored into seperate variables.
Is it possible that I could somehow get a JSON similar to the one autogenerated by spring boot above? Then, I could just use some JSON parser library to get whatever elements I want, put them into a class and return it.

Comment: Hmm well its most likely accessing the attributes via reflection. You could inject the ObjectMapper instance that Spring uses to serialize objects but then you would have to re parse the string to easily manipulate it.

Comment: @Thanks it worked! I have made a quick hack by using ObjectMapper to get JSON and then using JSON-simple to get the elements I want.

Answer (score 0):

For the Dev searching a similar thing... I had an issue writing my Discord login feature and I was high and low on Google...

So using some of the posts from here I propose my solution to you below.

```java
@GetMapping("/profile")
public String getProfilePage(Principal principal, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    // If the user requesting this page, is not an anonymous user
    if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        // parse the user for some basic information
        parseAuthorizedUser(authentication);
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

The parseAuthorizedUser was taken from one of the above answers and utilizing Simple Json

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to take the authentication and, in my case, loop over the authorities, and for each of the OAuth2UserAuthority I  make sure I'm checking my user role, and then breaking the authorities into a JSON Object, before then selecting just the attributes of the authority, and mapping it to a JSON Object as well. Then I just assurer it's not null or empty... and finally just set some atomicRefs I am using elsewhere

```java
private void parseAuthorizedUser(Authentication authentication) {
    // ... some previous code for profile basics
    authentication.getAuthorities().forEach(oAuth2UserAuthority ->  {
        if (Objects.equals("ROLE_USER", oAuth2UserAuthority.getAuthority())) {
            try {
                String jsonAttributes = JsonUtil.getObjectAsJson(oAuth2UserAuthority);
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonAttributes);
                if (Objects.nonNull(jsonObject)) {
                    JSONObject userAttributes = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("attributes");
                    if (Objects.nonNull(userAttributes) && !userAttributes.isEmpty()) {
                        discordId.set(userAttributes.get("id").toString());
                        discordAvatar.set(userAttributes.get("avatar").toString());
                    }
                }
            } catch (JsonProcessingException | ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
    // ... continue on with the rest of the method
}
```

As for the mention of `JsonUtil.getObjectAsJson(Object)` This is the method I use

```java
public static String getObjectAsJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
}
```

It's a vague idea that may point you along the right path.